# How to give a relative path of image in rdlc external image from design

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I wish to give a relative path in rdlc for image. I tried putting in value field of property as:

> file:\\\/images/sn_logo.gif

but it is not working. Is there any option because I can not give absolute path as the location for deployement will not be the same.

Comment: look on msdn for the URI it should handle making proper paths for you

Comment: Tried but didnt get. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem with deployment. The method I used is setting a parameter of image path in RDLC design. Assign the image path when I call the report viewer.

```
// I use 'GetCurrentDirectory' so that I can deploy it to anotherwhere.
string imagePath = @"file:///" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\image.png";

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]
    {
        new ReportParameter("imagePath ", imagePathParameterName) 
    });
```